# iOS animation malfunctioning, Y-Coordinate Problems

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

For hours I've been trying to solve the smallest animation glitch. My code successfully moves the view off screen, then animates it back in. It gets the x-coordinations right but the Y axis has behavior I don't understand. Here's the code:

```
func listTrans_slideIn (slideFrom: String) {
    //var newFrame = tableView.frame
    tableView.frame.origin.x = 1000
    //tableView.frame.origin.y = 100
    print("Table pushed to side")

    UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(1.375 /*Total*/, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeLinear, animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 1/1, animations:{
            self.tableView_toTLG_Top.constant = 130
            self.tableView_toSV_Left.constant = 0
            self.tableView_toSV_Right.constant = 0
            self.setupView()

            //newFrame.origin.y = self.hdrBox.frame.height+50
            //newFrame.origin.x = 0
            //self.tableView.frame = newFrame

            self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
        },
        completion: { finished in
            if (!finished) { return }

        })
}
```

The weird behavior is that if I put the correct y-coordinate in the animation keyframe, it comes in too high but then settles at the correct coordinate. If I put in a y-Coordinate that is too low, it comes in at the correct height but then settles too low.

As you can see, I've tried using frames and constraints. I've tried changing the height that I move it off screen to, but that seems to have no effect.

Anyone have any idea why I've spent half my day seeing this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an order of operations problem. The solution required that I move the animation to take place in the viewDidAppear.

Other notes:

- To make the animation look as smooth as possible, consider turning off the segue's animation.
- Also make sure you're running the segue call and animation in your main thread so that everything happens smoothly and without delay

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this :

```
  // Use the same value here and below, it moves it out of the screen
        self.tableView.center.y -= 500

 UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in

       // Then it comes back 
           self.tableView.center.y += 500
    })
```